# select option doesn't work in IE and SAFARI

Tags: jquery

the following code doesn't work in IE and Safari but works fine in firefox.

```
$('select#colors option').click(function() {
   //this is for testing but I get no alert in IE and Safari 
   alert('item selected');
}); 


<select id="colors" class="select">
     <option>Please select your style</option>
     <option>Navy</option>
     <option>Grey</option>
     <option>Black</option>
</select>
```

any ideas!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one instead

```
$('select#colors').bind('change', function() {
  alert('selected item changed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the function to the select rather than each option:

```
$('select#colors').click(function() {
   alert('item selected: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: this way as soon as I click on it I get the alert, it doesn't allow me to choose something

Comment: You need to either use the change() function instead of click, or watch for the value being changed in your click function